# Inhibit Sql Server Log Shipping Alerts during certain times

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, alerts

There are batch jobs that occur in the middle of the night, which cause log shipping backups to be delayed such that they exceed the alert threshold, and alerts are then emailed.

How can I disable these alerts during this period only?

I don't want to reduce the alerting threshold for the entire day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`sp_help_log_shipping_alert_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178562.aspx) to find the log shipping alert job ID and then use [`sp_update_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186976.aspx#TSQL) to suspend the job during maintenance. Enable it back when maintenance is done. I don't know whether the job would not immediately send an alert upon being enabled back though.

Comment: A slight variation of this appears to be just what I need - manually modifying the job (outside of the actual log shipping UI) to exclude certain hours in the alert job's schedule.

Comment: In my environment nightly batch jobs access the standby database so I turn off the LSAlert and LSRestore job schedules.  LSCopy continues so when the LSRestore schedule is turned on, the trn files are ready to be restored.